# How to convert .trc file type to text file using C++?

Tags: c++, binary

I have got a trace file that is binary in nature. I want to convert it to a text file and convert the data inside it to decimal form. I mean I am not sure, how to do this. This .trc file contains data in the form of telegrams and I want to extract particular kind of telegram and save them in text file which is readable in nature. I have to do all of this using C++.

Do you suggest any other language for it or does anyone has any idea about doing this in C++?

Comment: Just about any language should be fine. Do you have the file format specification?

Comment: If you have a description of the binary format (either given or reverse-engineered), you can create a [Kaitai struct](https://kaitai.io/) definition, which can automatically construct parsers in various programming languages for you, including C++.

Answer (score 0):

Binary trace files are usually encoded in proprietary formats. And there are applications or profilers specifically built to parse them.

Unless you know the file format, the only way to decode it is through reverse engineering. And in most cases it's not worth the effort.

Try to find documentation about it. Or maybe an application or utility that loads the file and exports data that is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are speaking about .trc binary files from Teledyne Lecroy Oscilloscopes, I would suggest to any of the following libraries out there for that:

https://pypi.org/project/lecroyparser/

https://github.com/jneer/lecroy-reader

https://github.com/yetifrisstlama/readTrc

https://igit.ific.uv.es/ferhue/lecroyparser